# regex range from numeric to a specific character

Tags: regex

Can I use a character as a delimiter of a range in regex? 
For example if I want the range to start index 1 and ends at character $. How can I do that?

{1, what do i put in here}

Comment: I have this string $CM-PRQRPMD$. I want to get the string inside the $ signs. Problem is that the string does not have a fix length, thus I can't use this {1,10}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Just use `+?\$`. For example, `.+?\$` matches at least one character up to and including the first `$`. (The `$` cannot be the first character, though; for that, simply use `.*?\$`.)

If you want to exclude the `$`, wrap it in a lookahead assertion: `.+?(?=\$)`.

**EDIT** (in response to clarification): To match identifiers between a pair of `$`, and assuming the `$`s belong to the identifier, you can just write this: `\$(.*?)\$`. The parentheses will create a capturing group, so that the `$`s are excluded from the match. If the delimiters *aren't* part of the identifier and you need to find multiple matches — e.g., `$AAA$BBB$` — then you'll need to use zero-width assertions: `(?<\$)(.*?)(?=\$)` so that the `$`s aren't absorbed while matching.

Comment: I have this string $CM-PRQRPMD$. I want to get the string inside the $ signs. Problem is that the string does not have a fix length, thus I can't use this {1,10}.

Answer (score 2):

this regex will match any letter, number or the $ sign. is that all you need?

```
[A-Za-z0-9\$]
```

**Update**:

given OP's comment to match "$CM-PRQRPMD$", use the following regex:

```
\$[A-Z-]+\$
```

Comment: no. when I say the range 0-9, you know what I'm talking about. when I say the "range" @-<, what does that include? who knows, it isn't defined. what you can do is use `\p{P}` which means "any punctuation", all of the \p{}'s are defined [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: also, note that there is a differences between square and curly brackets. `[123]` means "match a 1, 2, or 3" and `{1,2}` means match the previous thing 1 or 2 times.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I was misunderstanding the use of {}.

Comment: no prob. does my new regex solve your problem or would you like some more input?

Comment: I use one of the suggestion here also .+?(?=\$), but your explanation makes me use it properly and that solves the problem. Thank you!